# Importing on prem APIs to Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

It is my understanding that if I create a VPN gateway from my Azure VNET to my on prem network that I should be able to import APIs using the WSDL import into API Management.

Is this possible?  When in Azure it doesn't seem to be able to resolve my internal web api address.  Do I need to put some DNS stuff in to Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go to your Virtual Network in Azure that has the VPN Gateway resource and add your on-prem DNS stuff. API Management will then [use those name servers when resolving names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#a-nameconnect-vnet-aconnect-to-a-web-service-hosted-within-a-virtual-network).

Careful here, it will use those name servers for all queries, so make sure your on-prem DNS stuff resolves public names as well.

You'll need to [apply the Network Configuration updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/ApiManagementService/ApplyNetworkConfigurationUpdates) once you're done.